# Custom Id column in the Fluent NH entity name

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, s#arp-architecture, automapping

I am using S#arp architecture with Fluent Nhibernate and Automapper on a legacy DB.

The id column of one of the tables is different from the Automapping convention and therefore I tried to override it without success.  I end up with this error

> FluentNHibernate.Cfg.FluentConfigurationException
>   : An invalid or incomplete
>   configuration was used while creating
>   a SessionFactory. Check
>   PotentialReasons collection, and
>   InnerException for more detail.
>
> - Database was not configured
>     through Database method.
>
> ---
>
> FluentNHibernate.Cfg.FluentConfigurationException
>   : An invalid or incomplete
>   configuration was used while creating
>   a SessionFactory. Check
>   PotentialReasons collection, and
>   InnerException for more detail.
>
> - Database was not configured
>     through Database method.
>
>   ---- NHibernate.MappingException :
>     (XmlDocument)(3,6): XML validation
>     error: The element 'class' in
>     namespace 'urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2'
>     has invalid child element 'property'
>     in namespace
>     'urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2'. List of
>     possible elements expected: 'meta,
>     subselect, cache, synchronize,
>     comment, tuplizer, id, composite-id'
>     in namespace
>     'urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2'.   ----
>     System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaValidationException
>     : The element 'class' in namespace
>     'urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2' has
>     invalid child element 'property' in
>     namespace
>     'urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2'. List of
>     possible elements expected: 'meta,
>     subselect, cache, synchronize,
>     comment, tuplizer, id, composite-id'
>     in namespace
>     'urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2'.

***How do I user the Id automapper convention and set my custom column as the id through the override functionality?***

***Note:*** This is only for one entity. I don’t want to change the general id mapping convention
Here’s my current override function

```
  public class AuthMap : IAutoMappingOverride<Auth>
  {
    public void Override(AutoMapping<Auth> mapping)
    {
      mapping.Table("x_auth");
      mapping.Map(x => x.Id, "user_id");
      mapping.Map(x => x.SessId, "sess_id");
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured out:

Use it as

```
mapping.Id(x => x.Id).Column("user_id");
```